# ADB_SERVICES error on catlog errno = 5 I/O error

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, logging, system-error

I'm using catlog to find error for an issue. Although that issue did not reappear , I see a constant Error 
 `ADB_SERVICES ERROR: fd = 13, n = -1, errno = 5 (I/O error).` 
Sorry quite new to all this , not sure what should be done or Is it something I need to ignore?
few logs just before that error.
`InputReader AP_PROF: AppLaunch_dispatchPtr : Down` 
`AP_PROF unable to open /proc/mtrpof/ status entry`

Answer (score 2):

An I/O error may be indicative of filesystem corruption. If your device has a removable SD card, try removing it, putting it in a PC, and running a filesystem checker on it (such as `fsck` on Linux).

Comment: Thanks Dan : Is there any way I can run file system check on Android device itself? though enumlator or something?

Comment: I don't think so. To access the low level filesystem information, you need to be root, and the device needs to be unmounted. I suppose there might be a custom recovery that can do this, but I don't know of one.

Comment: My device is rooted and I can see an option Unmount SD card inside Settings->Storage .

Comment: If you're already rooted it might be worth looking for an app.

Comment: I was following the solution out here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself , but I'm not able to run the `fsck` command. I get can;t read '/etc/fstab' " No such file or directory