# fsck.auto: No such file or directory

Tags: busybox

So I'm trying to run fsck on my sdcard's ext4 partition and it doesn't work for some reason.

```
sh-4.1# fsck /dev/block/vold/179:2
fsck (busybox 1.21.0-Stericson, 2013-01-28 21:49:55 GMT)
fsck: fsck.auto: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why is says "No such file or directory"?

Comment: You shouldn't run `fsck` on a mounted device anyway: you need to unmount the device first so that `fsck` is free to make changes to the filesystem.

Comment: @DanHulme I unmounted it successfully and tried running fsck, I get the same message.

Comment: Have you tried running fsck.ext4 directly? (I'm not certain if it exists in busybox, but it's worth a try)

Comment: @onik Nope, the fsck.ext4 applet doesn't exist. I could simply do `fsck -t ext4` for the same function (right?), but I get same error as mentioned in this post. I'm guessing this is some issue with the binary bundled with busybox or maybe a permission error?

Comment: I have same problem here, but my SDCard has a vfat partition. So, it could not be an issue with Ext4 only. I have `busybox 1.22.1-Stericson, 2014-01-25`.

Comment: I have solved it by keeping this instructions: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself , except that I have used `fsck_msdos`. Maybe any other fsck variant would do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to include the `util-linux-fsck` package into your busybox image. The warning is saying that there is a file missing which the `util-linux-fsck` package provides.