# Recovering broken ecryptfs on SD-card with lollipop

Tags: external-sd, encryption, samsung-galaxy-s-5

This morning my phone froze and I had to hard reset it. Now when I boot and I insert my SD card, I get the following two messages:

1. Preparing SD card/checking for errors.
2. A dialog offering to encrypt my SD card. Here I can pick disable or continue, entering my device password.

So far I have only tried continue, with device password - then I have "sd card encryption encrypting sd card" alongside checking for errors.

So I've started digging. Firstly

```
$ mount | grep -i extsdcard                    
/dev/block/vold/179:65 /mnt/media_rw/extSdCard exfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/mnt/media_rw/extSdCard /storage/extSdCard sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,derive=unified 0 0
/storage/extSdCard /storage/extSdCard ecryptfs rw,seclabel,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_sig=094f421508772d43,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_enable_cc,ecryptfs_passthrough 0 0
```

So I can see I'm using ecryptfs and the sdcard is formatted exfat (yuck, but never mind). I was suspicious about the state of the exfat filesystem, so I followed the [top voted answer from this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself). `fsck.exfat /dev...` returns "no errors" so it is happy. I can browse to the sd card in the shell and see the files, but obviously not their contents, so the exfat filesystem appears intact.

So the problem I have is clearly with the ecryptfs layer. My question is therefore:

1. Is there a fsck-like tool I can run with some actual output to know what is going on for ecryptfs?
2. Failing that, can I extract from the device the key used to encrypt the sd card files?
3. If I just wait, will it fix itself? I guess not...

Ideally I'd like to recover those files, however there's nothing in there that's critical.

Environment: rooted lollipop samsung s5, stock firmware, custom recovery (twrp), busybox, supersu.

Answer (score 1):

Same phone, same problem (except my phone is not rooted), but it eventually resolved itself.

Posting the exact steps I followed in case it helps anyone else:

1. On first reboot (when the problem first occurred), the phone said it was preparing the device and then after a few seconds it told me the card was safe to remove (but I had not asked to unmount it). Going to the storage menu I had the same experience as the OP above. It just kept saying 'preparing device' and never finished.
2. Rebooted the device, same again as #1.
3. Repeated. Left the 'preparing device / checking for errors' message up for about 20 minutes this time but it still never completed.
4. Connected to computer, enabled USB debugging. Using `adb shell` command following the advice of OP I found the SD card mount directory was not accessible and I could not unmount it without root.
5. Rebooted the phone one last time. On initial boot, phone said 'preparing device' and then said 'SD card is encrypted'. I ignored this notification and was able to use `adb shell` to view the files and copy them to my PC. All files were readable. I then cleared the notification and all was well.

I don't think anything I did was responsible for fixing the problem, but if you follow the same steps then hopefully the same thing will happen for you.