# Using fsck to fix SD card returns invalid argument

Tags: external-sd

I'm having issues with my 64 GB micro-sd card that I can't find a solution to solve this problem.

I've reformatted from windows 7 using windows solution as well as the format software offered by the SD-card organization. I've also tried repairing and repartitioning through Aparted for Android. Nothing is working... The strange thing (to me at least) is that I can save things to the card itself.  The only thing is, when I go into the storage app in Android (by the way I'm on CM 12.1), Android only shows a gray bar and isn't able to identify what is on the card.  Also,  certain apps like teamviewer simply operate as if there is nothing in my SD-card slot.

When I followed the directions in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself), I got as far as the unmount step, at which point terminal tells me that it can't find the unmount I'm trying to point it to (/dev/block/vold/179:33).  What the directions don't mention in that link is what one can do if it can't find the device.  Can someone please give me a hand with this?  Thanks so much.

*In case anyone is wondering, I do have busybox installed.

*I also just noticed that when I go into storage, I don't even have an option to dismount the card...only erase.

Comment: The command is `umount`, without the "n", not `unmount`.

Comment: How does one decide which fsck (fsck.exfat, fsck.ms_dos...) is the correct one to use? 
Also, upon enteriing umount /dev/block/vold/179:33, I get a return of invalid argument

Comment: Even though I couldn't get umount /dev/block/vold/179:33 to work as it should, I went ahead and tried fsck -C -r /dev/block/vold/
179:33 and it returned a result of fsck: not found.  I'm at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: [Check and fix SD card errors within Android itself?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219879/218526)

Answer (score 0):

The command, Like most Linux and Unix commands is **umount**. Heaven knows why they could not use unmount, but since the Android kernel is Linux based, and you should have busybox installed, it should just be **umount**.

Comment: I'm looking at Aparted right now and under the config tab it's telling me that my device (mmcblk1) is at /dev/block/mmcblk1...
So my question is, perhaps I have to go with umount /dev/block/mmcblk1?