# Check and fix "formatted as internal" / encrypted SD Card i/o errors

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, file-system, adoptable-storage

Unfortunately I seem to have a problem with my filesystem on my as internal storage formatted SD card.
My problem is kind of related to this [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself) so I think it is worth mentioning here.

When I was restarting my device today I got the error that my SD card is corrupted. With a little bit of putting it in and out of the slot I eventually managed it to work again. Still the SD card is very slow and seems to have a corrupted file system. I managed to backup most of my data via `adb pull` but for some of the files I got an `i/o error`. I tried to run `fsck` as described in the other thread, but I cannot find any mount point of the SD card. I tried to `umount` every device in `/dev/block/vold/` but it always gives me `Invalid argument error`.

Of course I cannot try to fix it outside of my running device, as it is encrypted.

Is an as internal storage SD card behaving differently? Where is the mount point for this.