# Cant manage to mount sdcard on cyanogenmod

Tags: sd-card, bash

So I know that you are not found of cyanogenmod but I don't really know where else could I ask that.

So I'm trying to use a classe 10 SD-card which is called "corrupted" when I first insert it.

From [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself) I tried to used `mount | grep sdcard`but the output is empty even if I have a little icon of an sd card on the top of the screen.

Is there an other way to find this sdcard ?

Comment: Corrupted SD cards can't be mounted. Did you try formatting it first? Using a computer

Comment: @esQmo  I can, What shall I convert it in ?

Comment: FAT32 is the default filesystem