# sd card reports full when it isn't

Tags: insufficient-memory, internal-sd

I foolishly interrupted a file deletion operation on my internal sd card. (The card was full when I started) Now using any file explorer tool shows files and directories adding up to ~300 M, yet the entire 1.2 G sd card shows as full.

My tablet is rooted, and I have the file explorers set to show hidden files. I have connected to a Linux PC with adb and done ls -al on the sdcard. Linux disk tools also show the card full, but the extant files only adding up to ~300 M. Nothing shows what is consuming the extra space.

Please do not reply with advice to clear cache, look for dumps, etc. There is no visible or hidden file on the card which is consuming the space. There must be a corrupted file or directory attribute or table or some such.  Any advice as to how to reset this parameter(s) would be greatly appreciated.

On Linux I would run fsck on the disk - is there such a thing for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did indeed turn out to be file system corruption.  This [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself) helped me solve it but I don't think it is a duplicate because the accepted answer did not work for me.  However one of the other answers was very close to what I needed.

To fix:
Connected to my Linux PC with adb.
Then issued `adb shell mount | grep -i sdcard` command.  This told me that my sdcard filesystem was vfat, which is why the accepted answer to the other question didn't work for me. So going off another answer to that question I did a `adb shell fsck_msdos -y /dev/block/vold/93:80`.  This spat out a bunch of output and created a bunch of files in LOST.DIR on the sdcard which was awesome, because then I could get at them and delete them.  One was 770M which was the bulk of the missing space.

Problem solved.