# SD card became READ-ONLY

Tags: sd-card

This is the 3rd time my sd card has become read-only. I can still transfer files from it but not *into* it. I have tried all methods in the internet such as Diskpart and other softwares.

May I ask if you have encountered this as well and how did you fixed it?

> Phone: Huawei Y6 2018 [Android 8.1 Oreo]
>
> Sandisk SD Card Class 10 32 GB

Comment: What's the phone model, android version, SD card's model? Does it become read-only when you use a specific app?

Comment: Either the two don't like each other (wouldn't be the first time; in this case try a different brand of SD card) – or your card is about to die (and was mounted read-only due too many errors). There might be a third option, but it escapes me at the moment.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Huwaei Y6 2018, Android 8.1, not in a certain app, but also when it is read in a computer.

Comment: @Izzy are there ways to fix those errors?

Comment: if you have a terminal emulator, can you provide the output of `mount | grep -i storage` and `mount | grep -i sdcard`

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio https://imgur.com/a/JIpXWND

Comment: I advise to check if the SD card is in good condition by following the steps describe https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself . If it is in good condition, try to mount it with read-write permission

Comment: You can check filesystem errors from kernel log. If nothing works, zero out the whole disk (not the partition, not the filesystem). Then create partition table using fdisk/gdisk (I'd advise to avoid diskpart) and then create a filesystem using mkfs.<FS> (whatever FileSystem you want). If still the problem persists, consider replacing your card.

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow Not on the card itself. First thing I'd do is copy all data to a safe place (just in case the card is about to die). If you have a linux machine, you then afterwards can check the card using `badblocks` to see if there are any (usually it's either a lot of them, or none). Then copy the "secured data" to a new card of a different brand and try it again in your device. If that also "misbehaves", it might also be a hardware issue on the device itself.