# Repair SD card removed from phone without unmounting?

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi phone and I'm using a microSD card to store photos and other data. I wanted to copy photos to PC so, with the phone turned on I just removed the sd card from the phone.

Putting the card into PC doesn't work, it asks me to format it and putting it back on the phone it seems it's not recognized and when I click 'install SD' it just gives me an error.

I ran Easeus Data recovery and all data seems to kinda be there so it probably just needs to run like a 'chkdsk' for android SD cards :)

How can I repair this card so I can read the files normally on Windows and/or works again in Android without formatting and losing data?

Comment: See my answer to [Check and fix SD card errors within Android itself?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/check-and-fix-sd-card-errors-within-android-itself)

Answer (score 1):

tesdisk can probably also fix this (it detects the partition also) but I ended up using [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/data-recovery.php) to fix the partition table and save it, all data come up and it's working 100%. Easeus Partition Magic wasn't able to recover the partition in case anyone gets into the same trouble.

On DiskGenius:

1. First insert your SD card into your PC and run DiskGenius;
2. Click on Partition Recovery, `Whole Disk` and start the scan, it can take a few minutes to run;
3. While scanning, select `Reserve` for all partitions that appear;
4. Hopefully DiskGenius can find your missing partition that will appear in Green on the left Tree menu under your SD card;
5. If you are happy with the partitions found, just hit `Save All` and changes will be saved to the SD card

I was able to follow these steps and recover 100% functionality of the SD Card without formatting or losing any data. Be aware that DiskGenius is a paid app. I can guess the free [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) can also achieve this but I was afraid to do it with the more 'manual' steps required by testdisk.